# Updating dynamically jsp page in browser after POST http request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-post

I have the following project: a backend written in java; my Main class creates a listener on a log file, retrieves some info when the log is modified, and the creates an object called "Candidate", and send some of its attributes to a Servlet via a POST method. Everything works until here, and I get a 200 response code from the Servlet.

Then, I created a frontend (with bootstrap such that it looks nice) in an index.jsp file, which consist of a static part (background, messages, logos, etc.) and a dynamic part, which I want to update each time the log file is modified. A simplified version of the index.jsp can be found below, in which *firstName* is an example of the data that should arrive by the post request:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!-- If IE use the latest rendering engine -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- Set the page to the width of the device and set the zoon level -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">

<title>User Page</title>

<style>
 @import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');      
</style>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(images/xxxx.jpg); background-size:cover; " >


<% String firstName = (String) request.getParameter("firstName"); %>

<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
<h1 style="color:white">Hello 

<%if(firstName != null){%>

    <%=firstName %>
<%}%>
Welcome to this new page.</h1>

</div>
<img src="images/xx.png" style="width:35%;height:35%; padding-left: 10%; padding-top:10%"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My ultimate goal is that the user just sees the index.jsp page, which updates some of its content with data from the "new candidate" each time the log is modified.

To run my application, I have several run instances. I run the Main class, and on top of that, I run the index.jsp and MyServlet on the server. Is that the right way to run it?

Because when I do that, and I then modify the log, The main class console prints everything, showing that the POST request has been sent (i have tried to send the request to the Servlet or directly to the jsp file) but no request is received by my index.jsp (or at least it doesnt display it in the browser opened in eclipse), even after refreshing the page.

What does work, however, is when I modify manually the url in the browser to add the url query parameter with `?firstName=XXXX` and refresh, then the message is included in the index.jsp page. How can I make sure that the sent POST request through my backend dynamically modifies my index.jsp page?

Last note: when the log file is modified, the console prints the System.out.println with the corresponding first name as seen below in the doGet method, so that is how I assumed everything works up to there.

Here is the Servlet code:

```
package com.xyz.xxxxx;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        System.out.println("testing get: first name : " + firstName);   

        // forward request to jsp page 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request,response);

    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request,response);
    }


}
```

and File organization is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDYd1.jpg).

thank you for your help !

Comment: what framework You are familiar, or have some skills? Hard to ajaxify prpoject without, in raw jsp

Comment: None. But I can learn if you are able point me out exactly what framework I could use and why :-)

Comment: I use Wicket few years, but this is far from JSP, tell the true has nothing to JSP. There are few compatible with JSP, or using JSP in his presentation level

Comment: 1.) Can you confirm that the GET request is working correctly? What are you supplying as the path to reach the GET endpoint?

2.) How exactly are you testing the POST? Does this need to change the state i.e. If someone were to POST to the endpoint with a new name, the GET should supply the changed value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a leap of faith here and assume that you are looking to persist the values of the `firstName` from your `POST`

This will require you to adjust your code quite a bit, but I also don't want to just provide an implementation if this is a classroom project.

From the code snippet you've provided: Looks like you are trying to achieve the following:

1. GET -> display index.html with a name supplied by the post
2. POST -> change the name for a given session.

Therefore, you should be accessing the page using whatever you defined on your ServletClass.

Once you understand [HttpSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), you should get your desired effect

Comment: Thank you shinjw for your answer. Sorry for not being clear: I m not looking to persist the value of firstName i.e. each time the log is modified, I want the new name to be displayed. I used session when I was trying to make things work, but actually it doesn't help.

Comment: I've noticed that your last 3 questions all revolve around the same issue. What will trigger the log to be modified?

Comment: What you have currently written is a GET and a POST that will resolve the same way.

This means that any GET request with ?firstName=XYZ will prompt a new log event.

This also means that any POST with firstName=XYZ will do the same

Comment: You are right ;) The log will be trigged by an external program.

Comment: Yes, exactly but in the end I just need the post method, the get is there only such that I can test manually the url within my browser

Comment: I propose that you adjust your snippet to handle the log & changing the firstName in the doPost method. 

Once done, you can trim down your doGet and grab your firstName value from the session

Comment: Ps: summer time, working on personal projects, not classroom projects ;)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Will it be ajusted dynamically though ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by dynamically?

Comment: I mean that I want to see the changes immediately, even though the page might be already loaded in the browser with previous (or no) content.

Comment: The Right Way: You'll need to use WebSockets for that 

The Quick Way: Refresh the value using javascript.